# Objective-C: Compare unicode char with quotation mark

Tags: objective-c

```
if (myChar == '"') 
if ([myChar compare:@"\""]) 
if ([myChar isEqual:@"\""]) 
if (myChar == @"\"")
```

None of the comparisons above seem to work. I need to check if myChar, which is taken from an NSString, is a quotation mark.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first one works, actually, if myChar is actually a char.  The question is a bit unclear: are you trying to compare to a quote ('"') or a question mark ('?') ?

But yea, the first one works.

Comment: yea I just double checked and changed my answer -- the first given example should work, no?

Comment: That does not seem to work for me. The char will be either a letter A - Z or a " mark. I want to check for the " marks and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Is it an NSString or char * string of length 1? or a char (or a unichar)?  If it is the former, then the question was not phrased correctly, although I would be happy to respond to that instead.

Comment: In unicode, there're three double quotation marks. Left-right symmetric one " , the opening quote “ and the closing quote ”. Are you sure you have the symmetric one?